# To remove .pdf from cell

Tags: vba, excel

here's the problem, I have done up the code but it does not seem to work.. tried both method also not possible `str = Replace(str, ".pdf", Left(str, Len(str) - 4))
 str = Replace(str, ".pdf", Left(str, Len(str) - 4))`

can anyone help? Thanks in advance =)

```
Sub removepdfword()
Dim str As String
Dim row As Long
row = 1
str = Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(row))


Do While Sheet1.Range("A" & CStr(row)) <> ""

If Right(str, 4) = ".pdf" Then
     str = Replace(str, ".pdf", Left(str, Len(str) - 4))
     'str = Left(str, Len(str) - 4)
     MsgBox str
Else
End If
row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the Replace. You should use `str = Replace(str, ".pdf", "")` to remove the **.pdf** string.

Answer (score 0):

@PatricK already told you what was wrong in your `Replace()` function usage

but you're also missing to explicitly reference `Sheet1` worksheet in your ranges object, which then defaults to the currently *active* sheet (which may not be the one you need)

finally you could avoid looping and call `Replace()` method of `Range` object an do that in one shot:

```
With Sheet1 ' reference your sheet
    .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Replace what:=".pdf", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart ' call 'Replace()' method on referenced sheet column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
End With
```

Comment: @chanhongchon, any feedback?